# Select button in td redirect to another page

Tags: angular

i have tbody ,tr,td . the table is displayed. I need to add a column with copy button on each row.
On click of copy button the row must be copied and redirected to create page of invoice and load the control vendorname dropdown,grossamount textbox . since tr onclick is there that event is always firing .

Always (click)="navigateto(item.invoiceid) is fired . but i am getting vendor name in alert.

```
  Component.ts
toggle(val:any)

(

this.editRowid=val;
alert(val)
this.route.navigate(('/invoice/create'))!
)
Not redirected invoice/create
<tbody>
<tr *ngfor=let item of list.results (click)="navigateto(item.invoiceid)">
<td>{{item.vendorcode}}<\td>
<td>{{item.vendorname}}<\td>
<td>{{item.totalgrossamount}}<\td>
<td>{{item.Status}}<\td>
<td>
<button #item.Vendorcode (click)="toggle(item.VendorCode)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the `<td>` element that includes the `<button (click)="toggle(item.VendorCode)">` being a child of the `<tr (click)="navigateto(item.invoiceid)>`.

The `click` event that occurs on the button bubbles up to the `<tr>` and triggers that handler as well.

Easiest way to fix this would be to change `(click)="toggle(item.VendorCode)"` to `(click)="toggle($event, item.VendorCode)"` and change the `toggle` method like so:

```
toggle(event: Event, val:any) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // <-- this stops the event from bubbling up to <tr>
  this.editRowid=val;
  alert(val);
  this.route.navigate(['/invoice/create'|);
}
```

Comment: It is redirecting to create page.thanks.it should edit values in create page.do I need to pass parameter

Comment: In create page there is choose vendor,pop up opens there the vendor code must be load in textbox How to do..